# Should and can I move the gas pipes to make height for bathroom

Tags: bathroom, gas, rough-in

Trying to add a bathroom to the basement with the builder provided rough in which is next to furnace/heater (located at 10 ft right angle away from electrical boards and laundry)

- I see that the city's intake gas pipe from other corner (near electrical board) runs into the furnace area as shown in picture, cutting across the bathroom rough-in 8" off of the ceiling.
- I would love to have my bathroom be as high as possible, what do I need to get the gas line re-routed.

Location: Ottawa, Canada

Thanks in Advance.

[image: Basement gas pipe]

[image: rough-in between electrical and furnace/heater]

Comment: This is a pretty broad question for our Q&A format. It's not reasonable to ask us to write a guidebook for two trades. Have you investigated gas piping and house wiring? What specific questions do you have?

Comment: Thanks @isherwood I am new to this sub domain. Please correct me. Mainly I want the gas pipe to moved. I want to know the procedure/process involved in moved it.

Comment: As I said, it's not reasonable to ask for a complete tutorial on running black iron gas pipe and house wiring. There are plenty of resources to be found for that, but note that you may be required to hire a certified technician for the gas line. Here, we're happy to help with _more specific_ question about problems you encounter.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks @isherwood "Hiring a certified technician for the gas line" was the sort of direction I was looking for, I am new home buyer, please excuse. Will try to be more specific from next time

Comment: Please feel free to [edit] this question to make it more specific. As it stands, it may be closed for being too broad. Once you've made it more specific, you can get an actual answer, instead of just a comment. That will allow you to accept the answer and this question won't just wander around, abandoned, being bumped by the system every couple of months in a desperate attempt to get attention.

Comment: Re-routing the gas line now for the Pro is a lot easier now.  My nephew just extend his gas line and the plumber used gas compression fitting.  Raising it the 8" would take the Pro less than 1/2 hr for the two cuts, extension pieces, and compression coupling.